# LibGDX project in Android Studio can't import android libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I have a LibGDX project that I imported into Android Studio. When I try to import a library from Android SDK it can't find it:

```
import android.media.Image;
```

These are my dependancies in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.6.1'
compile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:2.6.0'
```

Comment: have you cross-checked these libs are present at proper location in system folders ?

Comment: Yes, they are within the standard sdk folder, which is selected in Module Settings.

Comment: Are you trying to import android dependencies in the core project? If so, don't.

Comment: I think you are missing the correct repository in your gradle file.

Comment: also, since this has nothing to do with libgdx. perhaps not tag it that way?

Comment: Well it does have something to do with libgdx as it wouldn't happen with normal android project. But I realized that, as donfuxx has mentioned, you shouldn't be importing android libs in the core project. I tried importing them in the android project and they were recognized. I compared android and core build.gradle files and the dependencies were written in android one.